# Highcharter - Having one or more of the grouping elements pre-selected

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I'm producing a set of charts using `highcharter`. I have items, which each have variants, and units sold by variant. I'm looking for a method by which I can choose which variants are pre-selected to appear on the chart.

Below is an example of the chart I produced:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)
library(viridis)

df <- tibble(item_name = c('beer','beer','soft drink','soft_drink'),
             units = c(15,50,25,10),
             variant_name = c('blonde','white','coke','lemonade'))

cols = as.vector(scales::viridis_pal(option = "turbo", direction = 1)(length(unique(df$variant_name))))


df %>%
  group_by(item_name) %>%
  arrange(desc(units)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  hchart(
    "column", hcaes(x = item_name, y = units, group = variant_name),
    stacking = "normal"
  ) %>%
  hc_colors(c(cols))
```

[image]

I would like to be able to pre-select, let's say 'blonde' and 'coke'. Other variants would have to be selected by clicking on the variant name in the chart:

[image]

I haven't been able to find a way to do that so far, the documentation for `highcharts` only points to doing so when you have multiple series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own JS function to load the elements. Where you can specify the `chart.series.load`, check this [link](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load) for extra info. Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)
library(viridis)

df <- tibble(item_name = c('beer','beer','soft drink','soft_drink'),
             units = c(15,50,25,10),
             variant_name = c('blonde','white','coke','lemonade'))

cols = as.vector(scales::viridis_pal(option = "turbo", direction = 1)(length(unique(df$variant_name))))


df %>%
  group_by(item_name) %>%
  arrange(desc(units)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  hchart(
    "column", hcaes(x = item_name, y = units, group = variant_name),
    stacking = "normal"
  ) %>%
  hc_chart(events = list(load = JS("function() {
  var chart = this;
  chart.series[1].setVisible(true)
  chart.series[2].setVisible(false)
  chart.series[3].setVisible(false)
  chart.series[4].setVisible(false)
  }"))) %>%
  hc_colors(c(cols))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you Quinten, the example does just what I asked for. Is there any way to make the false argument default?